Regex to Exclude records which does not have any vowels on Snowflake not working
I am trying for a regex function to exclude the records which does not have a vowel in it. Similar way to remove records which does not have consonant in it. It looks like the regular regex is not working as expected in snowflake.
select REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[aeiouy]', 'i') 



that would look for names with one letter that is a vocal, maybe you should look for some tutorials about regexp

@nbk thanks for the reply and apologies for my limited knowledge on regexes, do you know how does I can make it check if it is present in the whole word or not

You were close. Snowflake's regexp_like assumes start and end anchors, so your expression translates to
regexp_like(name, '^[aeiouy]$', 'i');

You want to modify that to
regexp_like(name, '.*[aeiouy].*', 'i');


Assuming you don't want any records with names having a vowel (including "y"), then you should use:
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[aeiouy]', 'i');


I used regexp_contains. Example below.
Ver 1 - Checks if text contains vowels:
WITH
  data_table AS (
  SELECT
    'a' AS name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'b'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'c'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'e'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'text'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'txt')
SELECT
  name,
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(name, r'[aeiouy]')
FROM
  data_table

Ver 2 - Moves the regexp_contains to the where function to filter it out of the data table:
WITH
  data_table AS (
  SELECT
    'a' AS name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'b'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'c'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'e'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'text'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'txt')
SELECT
  name
FROM
  data_table
WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(name, r'[aeiouy]') IS false

This is on BigQuery so the Snowflake equivalent should be:
WITH data_table AS (
  SELECT 'a' AS name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'e'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'text'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'txt'
)
SELECT name
FROM data_table
WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(name, '[aeiouy]');

